# Can't get svn branches list in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn

I'm currently working on Branch A and need to get updates from Branch B. When I tried "merge from branch" in xcode, the branches list is empty. Tried "merge to branch", it's empty too. However if I click "switch to branch", I can see all the branches and the trunk.

All the code is on SVN server...Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, open the branch you want to merge from. Then click **Source Control-->Switch To Branch** and (in the list) choose the branch you want to merge to. Xcode will open the branch you selected.

Now, select **Source Control-->Merge from Branch** and select the branch you want to merge from (the one opened at the beginning).